# How to I read cmd output in VB.NET from cmd shell?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, gnokii

I am using gnokii to send out SMSes.

My VB Codes:

```
Dim xCmd As String
xCmd = "cmd.exe /c echo msgcontent "| c:\gnokii\gnokii.exe --sendsms 12345678"
Shell(xCmd)
```

Points to note:

1. I did try to redirect the output to a .txt file but the .txt file appears to be empty. Besides, the program may have to send out multiple SMSes every second, so creating a .txt is not feasible.
2. Process.Start() is not feasible because I have to check if gnokii.exe is running.
3. I need the output to check if the SMS is sent successfully.
4. I tried using (codes below), but it didn't work either; no output was shown.

   Function exe(ByVal fileName, ByVal args)

   ```
   Dim p As Process = New Process
   Dim output As String

   With p
       .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
       .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
       .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
       .StartInfo.FileName = fileName
       .StartInfo.Arguments = args
       .Start()
       output = .StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
   End With

   Return output
   ```

   End Function

Comment: If you change your xCMD to have a > c:\xxx.txt does the content of xxx.txt contain the output you wanted?

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162078/pick-up-strings-from-cmd-command-process-startinfo) will help.

Comment: Okay, hi all, yesterday I found an answer on how to save the output into the .txt file. Simply change "... > xxx.txt" to "... 2> xxx.txt" Thanks for all the help that was given :)

Comment: Um, how do I do that? (New here)

Comment: Just click `Answer Your Question` at the bottom of this page.

Comment: OK, 2 is error out, not std out, thats why it wasnt working with other methods.

Comment: @BugFinder yes, I always thought 2> and > was the same thing, so I didn't thought that the number mattered.

Comment: Now you know otherwise :) 2> is different :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send output to a .txt file, (the best solution I can find)

REPLACE

```
xCmd = "cmd.exe /c echo msgcontent "| c:\gnokii\gnokii.exe --sendsms 12345678 > file.txt"
```

WITH

```
xCmd = "cmd.exe /c echo msgcontent "| c:\gnokii\gnokii.exe --sendsms 12345678 2> file.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    Dim p As Process = New Process
    Dim output As String

    With p
        .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        .StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        .StartInfo.FileName = fileName
        .StartInfo.Arguments = args
        .Start()
        output = .StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
        .WaitForExit()
    End With

    Return output
```

Comment: Um, isn't that what I quoted.. lol, but still, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Just seen this comment now after 9 years lol, the difference was `.WaitForExit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this 100% works but it will only show you the results

How to show shell results in vb.net:

```
'create 1 textbox1
'create 1 button1
'create 1 richtextbox1
'in the start up directory of this program make a file could 123.text
'------------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader
read = File.OpenText(Application.StartupPath & "\123.text")

Shell("cmd.exe /c" & TextBox1.Text + ">123.text")
Do Until read.EndOfStream
    RichTextBox1.Text = read.ReadLine & vbCrLf
Loop
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
'you can add on the top to create the file if it does not exists,   

If IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\123.text") = False Then
    IO.File.Create(Application.StartupPath & "\123.text")
End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code is also available at this link http://pastebin.com/iEhv61jG

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest something like this, myself.  This is similar to what someone else posted, but it offers a little more functionality, I think.

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Shell("cmd.exe /c " & TextBox1.Text + " > c:\temp\output.txt")
    Dim read As System.IO.StreamReader
    read = File.OpenText("c:\temp\output.txt")
    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    Do Until read.EndOfStream
        RichTextBox1.Text += read.ReadLine & vbCrLf
    Loop
    RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
    RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
End Class
```